# Popular vote for the 2016 House election

Tags: united-states, election, congress, reference-request

Where can I find the results (or at least preliminary results, if not all are counted yet) concerning the popular vote (as opposed to the number of representatives elected) for the national house of representatives election of 2016?

If possible, I would like to have the results state by state
(that is, how many people voted for a democratic candidate, how many for a republican, in each state), but even just the results aggregated nationally would be useful. Thanks for any help...

Edit: in particular, I am wondering: "who won the popular vote in the house elections, democrats or republicans"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Republicans are likely to have won the popular vote in the House elections this year.

---

[This article](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/onpolitics/2016/11/10/democrats-won-popular-vote-senate-too/93598998/) by USA Today states that:

> Republicans captured the majority of the "popular vote" for the House on Election Day, collecting about 56.3 million votes while Democrats got about 53.2 million, according to USA TODAY calculations. With a few races still undecided, Republicans so far hold a 239-193 majority for the next Congress.

---

However, Democrats won the popular vote for both the Senate and the Presidency.

Answer (score 3):

The [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/house) has it broken down by District, where you can get the totals for each by clicking on the district.  Not aggregated at all however.  You have your work cut out for you.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but with more than 400 districts, and the result given in a format I can't easily transform into a file I could manipulate using python or excel or anything, I'm afraid I will finish only when the next congress is elected :-)

Comment: Ballotpedia has prior years.  They may have something up in a couple of days

Answer (score 1):

*(P.S.: Since I "stole" @K Dog source, Ballotpedia, I'm marking my answer as Community Wiki)*

In [Ballotpedia](https://ballotpedia.org/Main_Page) you can see the results of the entire country and the results by state, both by popular vote and by percentage, besides the number of seats each party won. It shows the votes on third parties too. Search for the table "United States House Votes by Party and State" [in this page](https://ballotpedia.org/United_States_House_of_Representatives_elections,_2016) and you can find it.

Answer (score -1):

Look at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oArjXSYeg40u4qQRR93qveN2N1UELQ6v04_mamrKg9g/edit ... you can easily use this to calculate whatever you need.

Comment: Although the linked data may answer the question, please consider extracting some key points straight to your answer. Otherwise, the answer will be vulnerable to "link rot", e.g. if the linked document is moved or removed, your entire post will lose any sense and may be downvoted and subsequently deleted.